# Component not refreshing on redirect in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently starting to learn more about react, and I am doing small login/registration project with GoLang in backend. Here I have a small problem, when I log in, I redirect to Home.js and I need to refresh my navbar. But it doesn't work without me manually refreshing the page. I have same pattern with logout and it works, but when I login I have to refresh the page to load components.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Nav from './components/Nav';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Register from './pages/Register';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';


function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(''); 

  useEffect( () => {
    (
      async () => {
          const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/user', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            credentials: 'include'
          });

          const content = await response.json();
          setName(content.name);
      }
    )();
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Nav name={name} setName={setName} />

        <main className="form-signin">
            <Route path="/" exact component={() => <Home name={name} />} />
            <Route path="/login" component={() => <Login name={name} setName={setName} />} />
            <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
        </main>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Login.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';

export const Login = (props) => {
    const [email,setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password,setPassword] = useState('');
    const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false)

    const submit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            credentials: 'include',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: email,
                password: password
            })
        });
        const content = await response.json();
        setRedirect(true);
        props.setName(content.name);



    }

    if (redirect) {
        return <Redirect to = {{
            pathname: '/',
        }} />;
    }


    return (
        <form onSubmit={submit}>
            <h1 className="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please sign in</h1>

            <div className="form-floating">
                <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="name@example.com" required 
                    onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-floating">
                <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" required 
                     onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
            </div>

            <button className="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" >Sign in</button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Nav.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export const Nav = (props) => {
    const logout = async (e) => {        
        await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/logout', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            credentials: 'include'
        });
        props.setName('');
    };

    var menu;
    if (props.name === " ") {
        menu = (
            <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
                <li className="nav-item active">
                    <Link to="/login" className="nav-link" onClick={logout} >Logout</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        )
       console.log('ima ime '+ props.name)

    } else {
        menu = (
            <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
                <li className="nav-item active">
                    <Link to="/login" className="nav-link" >Login</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item active">
                    <Link to="/register" className="nav-link">Register</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        )
        console.log('nema ime ' + props.name)
    }


    return (
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">Home</Link>

                    <div>
                        {menu}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
    )
}

export default Nav
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react'

const Home = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.name ? 'Hi ' + props.name : 'You are not logged in'}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Register.js

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';

function Register() {
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [surname,setSurname] = useState('');
    const [email,setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password,setPassword] = useState('');
    const [redirect,setRedirect] = useState(false);

    const submit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/register', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: name.trim(),
                surname: surname,
                email: email,
                password: password
            })
        });

        setRedirect(true);
    }

    if (redirect) {
        return <Redirect to="/login" />;
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={submit}>
            <h1 className="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please register</h1>
            <div className="form-floating">
                <input className="form-control" placeholder="Name"
                    onChange= {e => setName(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label for="floatingInput">Name</label>
            </div>

            <div className="form-floating">
                <input className="form-control" placeholder="Surname" 
                    onChange= {e => setSurname(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label for="floatingInput">Surname</label>
            </div>

            <div className="form-floating">
                <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="name@example.com" required 
                    onChange= {e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-floating">
                <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" required 
                    onChange= {e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
            </div>

            <button className="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default Register
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At app.js change `useEffect` to `useState`

```
useState( () => {
    (
      async () => {
          const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/user', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            credentials: 'include'
          });

          const content = await response.json();
          setName(content.name);
          
      }
    )();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In App.js component you can’t use useEffect with no dependency array it will execute your useEffect hook on every render which is dangerous.

Reason for bug:  In your case when you call setName from Login it will set your name value to that u passed from Login and update state in App.js.But, as the App.js re-renders it will trigger a call to your useEffect and would rest your name value to whatever comes of the API call.So below is what you can do

Code would go like:

```
useEffect( () => {
    (
      async () => {
          const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/user', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            credentials: 'include'
          });

          const content = await response.json();
          setName(content.name);
      }
    )();
  },[]);
```

Now,this code block will be executed only once

2. In Login.js if you want to redirect user to a route you can use history which is provided by useHistory hook of react-router-dom.More on this here:
   https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Comment: Thank you for your response, I recognized the problem with useEffet(), but can you show me how to implement useHistory in my example in Login.js ?

Comment: You can replace the setRedirect(true) with history.push(your path).
Also If I have answered your query can you mark this as close.

Comment: I am sorry but bug still persits, when I reload the page data is ok